# How to fix failed to open a session for the virtual machine kali-linux-2020.3-vbox-amd34

Tags: linux

when I select Kali Linux and I click **Start** I get this error message :

```
Failed to load R0 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VMMR0.r0: Signature #2/3: Expected at least 2 valid paths, not 1.: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUP_VP_UNEXPECTED_VALID_PATH_COUNT).
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUP_VP_UNEXPECTED_VALID_PATH_COUNT).
```

anyone know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was -

Uninstall Virtualbox's Extension Pack, then uninstall Virtualbox. Restart your computer.

I installed 6.0.24 version of Virtualbox and its Extension Pack.

Right-click the Virtualbox installer and choose Run As Administrator. Let the installation complete. Do not install the Extension Pack for now. Restart your computer again.

Now try Virtualbox.