# VERR_SUP_VP_UNEXPECTED_VALID_PATH_COUNT

Tags: virtualbox

i had this problem. in my case , am working in windows 7 64 bits in my real machine, with this scenary :

[image]

my problem

1- outer virtual machine : virtualbox Versión 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2). - virtual machine with windows 7 64 bits, PAE/NX=disable, VT-x/AMD-V=enable, nested paging=enable, guest additions installed, memory 1536MB

2- inner virtual machine : virtualbox Versión 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2). - virtual machine with windows 7, 64 bits, PAE/NX=disable, VT-x/AMD-V=disable, nested paging=enable, memory 512MB

my solution

a - inside machine 1, all programs closed, uninstall guest adittions, restart mv normally
b - inside machine 1, uninstall inner virtualbox Versión 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2), restart mv normally
c - inside machine 1, install virtualbox Versión 6.0.24 r139119 (Qt5.6.2)
d - in the same machine, settings, PAE/NX=disable, VT-x/AMD-V=disable, nested paging=enable, VT-x/AMD-V=enable

test again and work for me. I don't know if it works in linux but maybe it will help you.

this is direct link to virtualbox version 6.0.24

[VirtualBox 6.0.24 (released July 14 2020)](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_0)

[image]

Comment: I think this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65733379/5840973